# Use a function or method with variables in them in another class? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, methods, arguments

Im trying to use a method or function from another class, This is how my code looks from the class i want to use the functions from.

```
public class Crypting
{
    internal static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

     // My code is in here
    }
```

So I try to use this function in my main form like this.

```
 private void primeButton14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Crypting.EncryptFile();
    }
```

It gets red marked and says "No overload for method 'EncryptFile' takes 0 arguments"

When I remove `string inputFile, string outputFile`
It does not get red marked however I need those 2 arguments for that function to work.

How do I use this function in my main form? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Pass two arguments when you are calling the method, that is why you defined them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is pretty clear: you have to provide arguments:

```
EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile) // see the two arguments, inputFile and outputFile?
```

Call it e.g. like this:

```
Crypting.EncryptFile(@"c:\myinputfile.txt", @"c:\myoutputfile.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you I must have been a fool missing that!

Answer (score 0):

your function EncryptFile needs two parameters to work on, as you specified i.e. input file and output file location. you need to pass them while calling the method. like `Crypting.EncryptFile("somestring", "somestring");`

Answer (score 0):

To add what @roryap said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004763/327079 - while defining your method, you can also define default values for the parameters on the method:

```
public class Crypting
{
    internal static void EncryptFile(string inputFile = @"c:\input.txt", string outputFile = @"c:\output.txt")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inputFile: {0} outputFile: {1}", inputFile, outputFile);
    }
}
```

Then if you use it, you can get following results:

```
Crypting.EncryptFile(); -> inputFile: c:\input.txt outputFile: c:\output.txt
Crypting.EncryptFile(@"c:\otherInputFile.txt"); -> inputFile: c:\otherInputFile.txt outputFile: c:\output.txt
Crypting.EncryptFile(@"c:\otherInputFile.txt", @"c:\otherOutputFile.txt"); -> inputFile: c:\otherInputFile.txt outputFile: c:\otherOutputFile.txt
```

It's hard to tell whether it will work for your actual case, but that's what language offers you.